# Scene Delegate doesnt update View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do i achieve this code in Scene Delegate

```
  // App Delegate
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
```

Because I need to get some data from the callback. Currently, the callback won't trigger the App Delegate. Imagine that the callback is an OAuth flow.

I found a solution but it didn't work well

```
// Scene Delegate
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
            return
        }

        SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: nil)
     }
```

because I need to pass options value to this scene. How would I achieve AppDelegate method in Scene Delegate?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is how to pass the options param, try the following code. Basically `UIOpenURLContext` has two members variables **url** and **options**, you have to map that `ApplicationDelegate` options.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let urlContext = URLContexts.first else {
            return
        }

        let url = urlContext.url

        let options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation : urlContext.options.annotation as Any,
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication : urlContext.options.sourceApplication as Any,
          UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.openInPlace : urlContext.options.openInPlace
        ]

        SCSDKLoginClient.application(
            UIApplication.shared,
            open: url,
            options: options)
    }
```

Disclaimer - I didn't test Snapchat code, just try to give you an idea.